# How to limit results count of a stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for a way I can limit the number of results from such a stream:

```
return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Global.updatesRef.streamData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
          if (snap.hasError) {
            print(snap.error);
          }
          if (snap.hasData) {
            List<Update> updates = (snap.data)
                .where((item) =>
                    item.status == 'online' &&
                    item.type == 'market' &&
                    item.id != widget.productId)
                .toList();
            if (updates.length > 0) {..
```

This gives me all the results of the query, but I want to limit the count here within the stream to let say just **5** items.

I am using provider to get firestore data. So the provider store is shared with other screens that don't need any limitation of the result count at least for now.

So if I can do that depending on the screen or the widget, it will be nice.

Comment: Add a parameter for number of results to the streamData() method that defaults to not limiting the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.take(5)` on the stream. `.take` will return first `count` data events of the stream as a new one.

> Provides at most the first count data events of this stream.

Docs: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Stream/take.html

Here is example how that works:

```
void main() {
  Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).take(5).forEach((val) {
    print(val); // prints: 1 2 3 4 5
  });
}
```

Comment: I want to reduce the results only after the filtering. (.where)

Comment: You can use `.take` after `.where`. `Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])
    .where((i) => i % 2 == 0)
    .take(5).forEach((val) {
    print(val); // prints: 2 4 6 8 10
  });`